# Finding all words (including contractions) not ending in 's

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to find all non-numerical words in a document in order to list them and count how often they appear. In this case, a 'word' has the following conditions:

- Exclude the `'s` in possessives like `John's` -> matches `John`
- Include contractions like `you're` and `isn't` -> matches `you're` and `isn't`
- Split words with a hyphen like `dog-friendly` -> matches `dog` and `friendly`

I can match words and split hyphenated words with

```regex
\w+
```

And match words as well as ignore `'s` with

```regex
\w*+(?<!'s)
```

(although this messes with contractions)

How can I combine these two patterns to match what I'm asking?  Do I need to use non-fixed-length lookbehinds?

The best I could come up with is this:

```regex
(?<!')\w+
```

But it doesn't work as required for contractions

https://regex101.com/r/rRhONT/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this regex would be fine for you :

```
\w+('\w+)?(?<!('s))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Q1J46N/2

Comment: Yes, thanks! Can you explain why the `?` quantifier makes it work?

Comment: In regex, use `(expression)?` to make an expression _optionnal_. So i took you regex `\w+(?<!'s)` and add the optionnal `'\w+` which will math any word OR any word with '..... after this word, exept 's because we use `(?<!'s)`  after!